# How to load a URL as the source code for source code highlighting in highlight.js?

Tags: web, highlight.js

To use highlight.js, the following code would work:

```
<pre><code> CODE HERE </code></pre>
```

But what if I want some external source file loaded from a URL to be highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would use the highlightBlock method of the hljs object. When you load the highlight.js script you will have access to the hljs object.

**html**

```
<div id="after-load-code">
    <pre><code class="javascript">
        // your ajax content here
    </code></pre>
</div>
```

When you make an ajax request and fill the HTML block with whatever it is you needed then you can use highlightjs to style it for you with the following code.

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
block = document.getElementById('after-load-code');
code_blocks = block.querySelectorAll('code');

for( var i = 0; i < code_blocks.length; i++) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(code_blocks[i]);
}
```

If you are more comfortable using jQuery here is a jQuery example

**jQuery example**

```
$('#after-load-code pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
})
```